What is correct APPLICATION_ID if integrated both ADMOB and AdManager
I've integrated both SDKs in my app and using GAM's APPLICATION_ID till now and things seem to be working fine now except almost 50% of ads in ADMOB network are requested as non-personalised ads, which is causing drop in eCPM and match rate and eventually impacting overall revenue.
I've verified integration along with COPPA flags and GDPR and everything seem to be correct then I found that I'm using this GAM's ID in Manifest and had a doubt that could this cause issue?
The ratio for non-restricted and Personalization disabled are not that bad for India locale but in US and rest of world only ~20% request are non-restricted.
Which ID should I use here?
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ADMOB's ID or GAM's ID" />

SDK version:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0

Any help would be appreciated.
